# Como ocultar classe ao clicar fora de um input

Tags: javascript, input

Tenho uma dúvida com `hide()` e `show()` tenho um **input** que ao ser ativado, deve exibir a classe "resultado" e ao clicar fora do input deve ocultar a classe "resultado" ou até que clique no link dos resultados da pesquisa.

```js
function menuFiltro() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("pesquisa-int");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();                
    var p = document.getElementById('lista');
    var filhos = p.childNodes;
    for( i = filhos.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if( filhos[i].tagName == 'LI' ) {
            p.removeChild( filhos[i] );
        }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu").length; index++) {        
        ul =  document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];            
        ul.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");            
        for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            const element = li[i];
            a = element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                newLi.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML;
                p.appendChild(newLi);
            }

        }           
    }       
  }
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pesquisa-int" onkeyup="menuFiltro()" placeholder="Pesquisar" title="Pesquisa" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="resultado">
     <ul id="lista">
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Como poderia fazer para que a div "resultado" seja exibida quando o input  estiver selecionado, e fique oculta ao clicar fora input ou até que o link seja clicado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode está utilizando jQuery e seus eventos [`focusin`](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) e [`focusout`](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pesquisa-int').focusin(function() {
    $('.resultado').show(); // exibe o conteúdo da div após o input está em foco.
  });
  $('#pesquisa-int').focusout(function() {
    $('.resultado').hide(200); // oculta o conteúdo da div após o input sair do foco.
  });
});

function menuFiltro() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("pesquisa-int");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();                
    var p = document.getElementById('lista');
    var filhos = p.childNodes;
    for( i = filhos.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if( filhos[i].tagName == 'LI' ) {
            p.removeChild( filhos[i] );
        }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu").length; index++) {        
        ul =  document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];            
        ul.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");            
        for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            const element = li[i];
            a = element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                newLi.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML;
                p.appendChild(newLi);
            }
            
        }           
    }       
  }
```

```css
.resultado {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pesquisa-int" onkeyup="menuFiltro()" placeholder="Pesquisar" title="Pesquisa" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="resultado">
     <ul id="lista">
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: É esse o caminho, porém ao clicar no link do <li> o evento oculta a classe antes de executar o link.

Comment: é porque não está definido nenhum link no `href` e por a cerquilha não ter nenhuma ação por isso ela oculta.

Comment: tente colocar um link ai, ao clicar nele será redirecionado automaticamente e a classe ocultada

Comment: Ele fechou antes mesmo com um url definido, só foi com delay $('.resultado').hide(1000);

Comment: Maravilha! mas seria um problema o uso do delay, ou não?

Comment: Ele atrapalha um pouco por conta da animação.

Comment: Da pra criar uma condição para ocultar somente se clicar em uma tag <a> ou clicar fora de todo conteúdo.

Comment: utilizei delay $('.resultado').hide(200); e atendeu ao clique sem transição de movimento. Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127247/discussion-between-kim-hanneman-and-gleisin-dev).

Answer (score 2):

Também dá para fazer esse mostrar ou esconder da classe `resultado` com base no focus do `<input>` apenas com JavaScript puro. Para tal precisa de utilizar os eventos `focusout`, `focusin` e manipular a propriedade `display` do mesmo:

```
const inputPesquisa = document.getElementById("pesquisa-int");
const classeResultado = document.querySelector(".resultado");
const esconderResultado = () => classeResultado.style.display = "none";
const mostrarResultado = () => classeResultado.style.display = "block";
inputPesquisa.addEventListener("focusout", mostrarResultado);
inputPesquisa.addEventListener("focusin", esconderResultado);
```

Exemplo no seu código:

```js
const inputPesquisa = document.getElementById("pesquisa-int");
const classeResultado = document.querySelector(".resultado");
const esconderResultado = () => classeResultado.style.display = "none";
const mostrarResultado = () => classeResultado.style.display = "block";
inputPesquisa.addEventListener("focusout", mostrarResultado);
inputPesquisa.addEventListener("focusin", esconderResultado);

function menuFiltro() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("pesquisa-int");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();                
    var p = document.getElementById('lista');
    var filhos = p.childNodes;
    for( i = filhos.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if( filhos[i].tagName == 'LI' ) {
            p.removeChild( filhos[i] );
        }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu").length; index++) {        
        ul =  document.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];            
        ul.getElementsByClassName("grupo-menu")[index];
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");            
        for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            const element = li[i];
            a = element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                newLi.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML;
                p.appendChild(newLi);
            }

        }           
    }       
  }
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pesquisa-int" onkeyup="menuFiltro()" placeholder="Pesquisar" title="Pesquisa" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="resultado">
     <ul id="lista">
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Resultado 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```